# RNN Text Generation: How to balance training/test lost with validation loss?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp, recurrent-neural-network

I'm working on a short project that involves implementing a character RNN for text generation. My model uses a single LSTM layer with varying units (messing around with between 50 and 500), dropout at a rate of 0.2, and softmax activation. I'm using RMSprop with a learning rate of 0.01.

My issue is that I can't find a good way to characterize the validation loss. I'm using a validation split of 0.3 and I'm finding that the validation loss starts to become constant after only a few epochs (maybe 2-5 or so) while the training loss keeps decreasing. **Does validation loss carry much weight in this sort of problem?** The purpose of the model is to generate new strings, so quantifying the validation loss with other strings seems... pointless?

It's hard for me to really find the best model since qualitatively I get the sense that the best model is trained for more epochs than it takes for the validation loss to stop changing but also for fewer epochs than it takes for the training loss to start increasing. I would really appreciate any advice you have regarding this problem as well as any general advice about RNN's for text generation, especially regarding dropout and overfitting. Thanks!

This is the code for fitting the model for every epoch. The callback is a custom callback that just prints a few tests. I'm now realizing that history_callback.history['loss'] is probably the training loss isn't it...

```
for i in range(num_epochs):
    history_callback = model.fit(x, y,
          batch_size=128,
          epochs=1,
          callbacks=[print_callback],
          validation_split=0.3)
    loss_history.append(history_callback.history['loss'])
    validation_loss_history.append(history_callback.history['val_loss'])
```

My intention for this model isn't to replicate sentences from the training data, rather, I'd like to generate sentence from the same distribution that I'm training on.

Comment: *Test* loss keeps decreasing?

Comment: As @desertnaut suggests, test and validation loss should be behaving similarly, they are both held-out datasets.

Comment: I assumed that the validation set is held out for all epochs of training but the test set is included in training for different epochs i.e. the model is never trained on the validation set but part of the test set can become part of the training set between different epochs. Is this wrong? Maybe what I'm thinking of as the test loss is actually training loss?

Comment: Consider clarifying your question in these 2 ways: 1) include some actual or pseudo code that show how you're using the training/testing/validation data. And 2) add details about your intentions for this text generator: roughly speaking, if you want your model to be good at regurgitating the sentences in your training data, then your concern is training loss, and you don't need to worry about validation data. Alternatively, if you want your model to be good at generating text for unseen data from the same distribution as your training data, then you want the best possible validation accuracy.

Comment: Based on the update, your concern is performance on the distribution your training data was sampled from (i.e., you want generalization). However, based on your question, it sounds like the validation loss stops changing past a certain point. Is this correct? If it's correct, then your model's generalization is (approximately) independent of how long you train, so you might as well stop when you hit the validation loss plateau.

Comment: If it's incorrect, then you want to stop training when your validation loss begins increasing (or when it plateaus). This is called early stopping [1], it helps your model generalize. You may also wish to review training, validation, and testing data [2], and consider updating your question, as the current "training/test loss" comment is confusing.

  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_stopping#Validation-based_early_stopping
  [2]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training,_validation,_and_test_sets

Comment: The validation loss drops to a constant for about 5 epochs and then slowly starts to increase, so I think I need to employ early stopping like you suggested. I was confused about the differentiation between training loss and test loss between epochs, so I'll get that cleared up. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! Welcome to SO! On a different note, voting up [1] comments, questions, and answers that you find useful helps others find good information, and is a pat on the back for contributors. [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes `history_callback.history['loss']` is Training Loss and `history_callback.history['val_loss']` is the Validation Loss.
2. Yes, `Validation Loss` **carries weight** in this sort of problem because you just don't want to replicate the sentences which are given during Training but you want to learn the patterns from the Training Data and generate new sentences when it sees a new data.
3. From the information you mentioned in the question and from the insights identified from comments (thanks to Brian Bartoldson), it is understood that your model is `overfitting`. In addition to `EarlyStopping` and `dropout`, you can try the below mentioned techniques to mitigate `overfitting` problem.

3.a. `Shuffle` the Data, by using `shuffle=True` in `model.fit`. Code is shown below

3.b. Use `recurrent_dropout`. For example, If we set the value of `Recurrent Dropout` as `0.2` in a `Recurrent Layer (LSTM)`, it means that it will consider only `80%` of the `Time Steps` for that `Recurrent Layer (LSTM)`.

3.c. Use `Regularization`. You can try `l1 Regularization` or `l1_l2 Regularization` as well for the arguments, `kernel_regularizer`, `recurrent_regularizer`, `bias_regularizer`, `activity_regularizer` of the `LSTM` Layer.

Sample code to use `Shuffle`, `Early Stopping`, `Recurrent_Dropout`, `Regularization` is shown below:

```
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()

Regularizer = l2(0.001)

model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units = 50, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=Regularizer ,
    recurrent_regularizer=Regularizer , bias_regularizer=Regularizer , activity_regularizer=Regularizer, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.3))

callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=15)

history_callback = model.fit(x, y,
          batch_size=128,
          epochs=1,
          callbacks=[print_callback, callback],
          validation_split=0.3, shuffle = True)
```

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!